# Why does the RFC version of HKDF-Expand start the counter at 1?

Tags: hmac, key-derivation, hkdf

In [RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869#section-2.3), the definition of HKDF-Expand is given as follows, with the terminating counter value ranging from 1 to (presumably) 255:

```
The output OKM is calculated as follows:

   N = ceil(L/HashLen)
   T = T(1) | T(2) | T(3) | ... | T(N)
   OKM = first L octets of T

   where:
   T(0) = empty string (zero length)
   T(1) = HMAC-Hash(PRK, T(0) | info | 0x01)
   T(2) = HMAC-Hash(PRK, T(1) | info | 0x02)
   T(3) = HMAC-Hash(PRK, T(2) | info | 0x03)
   ...
```

However, in section 4.2 of the [HKDF paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/264.pdf) the same function is instead defined with the counter value starting at 0. Is there some subtle reason to avoid a 0 value in this terminal counter byte?

Comment: It is a matter of taste...

Comment: It's not the only modification the IETF people ever made to an algorithm. The academic version of ChaCha20 cipher had 64-bit IV and 64-big counter, they changed it to 96-bit IV and 32-bit counter so as to make it fit better for Internet protocols.

Comment: My final comment here is that, these kind of questions are better asked to the people made the decision. The drafters of the RFC can probably still be reached from the contacts listed in the last page of that RFC. One of them is a [member](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/86083/hugo-krawczyk) of this community (albeit inactive).

Comment: Seconded, but I will add that it would be helpful if they could answer here, or - if you receive an answer - to post it as a self answer.

Comment: Only speculating, but in terms of security I think the difference doesn't matter as the security relies on the PRF security of HMAC. But maybe it's make is "easy" to implement naively as the loop counter is the same as the counter value and no need to do a "-1"?

Comment: OK, I will ask on the CFRG mailing list as they may know. It seems a little odd to restrict it to a single byte and then to eliminate 1/256th of the capacity!

Comment: with sha256, a 255 counter amounts to around 7MB of random data.

Comment: Wouldn't that be $255 \cdot 32$ bytes, which is $(2^8 - 1) \cdot (2^5) = 2^{13} - 32 = 8 Ki - 32$ bytes of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hugo Krawczyk [answered on the CFRG mailing list](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cfrg/mA5KlWBCkOuYp6Z8m3b6vHa2Llw/) that the RFC version was adjusted to be compatible with [IKE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296.html#section-2.13), which starts the counter at 1:

> Good question. I believe (I checked some old email of mine with Pasi) this
> was done for compatibility with the definition of HKDF in IKE (which is
> when I originally designed HKDF,  though without a name and published
> analysis). I wasn't too happy about being limited by backwards
> compatibility but it was judged at the time as one less hurdle for adoption.

Answer (score 0):

This HKDF RFC change to start `HKDF-Extract` counter at `1` also made it (likely unintentionally) output-incompatible with [SP800-108](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-108/final) KDFs, which end their data buffers with a big-endian 4-byte `length-of-derived-keying-material-in-bits`. Starting `HKDF-Extract` counter at `1` corresponds to an odd number of requested `SP800-108` bits (indivisible into bytes), which kills the idea of making `HKDF-Extract` and `SP800-108` outputs match for some combination of HKDF's `"info"` and SP800-108's `"label"/"context"`.